# i need help to implement a semaphore

Tags: c, process, operating-system, semaphore, c89

I have an idea but I don't know how I could do it, from a parent process with fork () I created N child processes.
To make the child processes perform a certain action one at a time I would like to use a series of semaphores, which are set to 0 and only the one that corresponds to the child that must perform the action to 1. how can I do?
i'm working in c89.

Comment: if you are using fork, it means you are developping on top of an OS. This OS probably already provides a semaphore or mutex functionality. Is there a specific reason why you want to re-implement the semaphore functionality ?

Comment: i'm doing a project that involves 3 proocesses

Comment: Do you want the child processes to perform their respective tasks in a certain order? For example, should child #1 perform its task first, then child #2, then child #3? Or do you only want to make sure that the child processes don't perform their respective tasks at the same time, but the order that the child processes perform their respective tasks does not matter?

Comment: no i want the child processes   to perform their respective tasks in a certain order like in your first example